# why javascripts functions are not loaded one after the other?

Tags: javascript

at the **beginning of my html** iam initializing variable "`movieSRC`" like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        var activeStep = getUrlVars();
        var movieSRC;

        cloud.getStepsForModules(activeStep.module, "UMCK").then(function(steps) {

            var calculatedStep = activeStep.step - 1;
            movieSRC = steps.steps[calculatedStep].movie;

        });
```

at the **end** of my **html** i have some function for [videojs](http://www.videojs.com/docs/api/).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    _V_("movie").ready(function() {
        var myPlayer = this;
        myPlayer.src(movieSRC);
</script>
</html>
```

I dont understand why a html **part at the end** will be loaded first and a `one after the other` at the **beginning** of my page as a second one. i need it opposite!
i need to keep `videojs` script at the end of the page because  with video should be loaded first and just after that a script.

conclusion: `movieSRC in myPlayer.src(movieSRC)` is alwas empty :(, but why?

Comment: Maybe `getStepsForModules` is an asynchronous function? Why else would you need a `.then()`?

Comment: can i call such a function other way?

Comment: No, but you can reorganize the event in your script and make proper use of the callback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is executing in order.  First a couple of variables are declared, then a function is executed, then later that part at the end executes.  What you're overlooking is that the function being executed is asynchronous.  And no matter how fast it runs, it's *highly unlikely* that it will complete before the page finishes loading.

This is asynchronous:

```
cloud.getStepsForModules(activeStep.module, "UMCK")
```

So *while it's executing* everything else is loading.  Anything that you need to happen *after* it executes will need to be invoked from its `.then()` handler:

```
cloud.getStepsForModules(activeStep.module, "UMCK").then(function(steps) {

    var calculatedStep = activeStep.step - 1;
    movieSRC = steps.steps[calculatedStep].movie;

    // I don't know this plugin, but find your "myPlayer" here somehow
    myPlayer.src(movieSRC);

});
```

Or perhaps this order will make more sense overall for the plugin:

```
_V_("movie").ready(function() {
    var myPlayer = this;

    cloud.getStepsForModules(activeStep.module, "UMCK").then(function(steps) {
        var calculatedStep = activeStep.step - 1;
        movieSRC = steps.steps[calculatedStep].movie;
        myPlayer.src(movieSRC);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, the script at the end is being evaluated before the response returns from the cloud.getStepsForModules function above.

Also, there's a syntax error in the second script - you're missing the closing brace/paren/semicolon set.

Try putting the function that uses the result in the callback, like

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var activeStep = getUrlVars();
    var movieSRC;

    cloud.getStepsForModules(activeStep.module, "UMCK").then(function(steps) {

        var calculatedStep = activeStep.step - 1;
        movieSRC = steps.steps[calculatedStep].movie;
        _V_("movie").ready(function() {
           var myPlayer = this;
            myPlayer.src(movieSRC);
            });

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript code does execute in the order it appears. However, there are functions that are asynchronous, which means they execute in a separate thread. Is it possible that your first function is asynchronous?

If you want to make sure that certain code is executed AFTER an asynchronous function, call that code in the asynchronous function's callback method.